# Make a request with emoji search term twitter

Tags: python, twitter, dataset, emoji

I have a little problem with the Twitter Api. My goal is to create a dataset with tweets containing "" (this is a Twitter smiley that I just copied on Twitter). But when I make a request with this search term I get an empty list. I tested with ":)" and it works I collected tweets containing ":)" but the dataset would be much more intersting with the tweets containing the Twitter emojis. I assume there is a conversion problem between utf8, ascii or Twitter encoding code but I can't find it...

```
# coding: utf8
import csv
import twitter
CONSUMER_KEY = '...'
CONSUMER_SECRET = '...'
ACCESS_TOKEN = '...'
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = '...'
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key=CONSUMER_KEY,
                  consumer_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET,
                  access_token_key=ACCESS_TOKEN,
                  access_token_secret=ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

users = api.GetSearch(term=" ",lang="fr",count=200)
print users
```

Comment: My suggestion would be to manually find a tweet that contains this character, get it from the API by its ID and see how this character is encoded in the response. It would probably be encoded in utf-8 (`\u...`)

Comment: Yes for example  is \U0001f61b, but how can i search this ? If I put it on search term it will search for the string "\U0001f61b", doesn't it?
And what's weird is that in my terminal if I print the sentence I can see the smiley but if I just ask without printing for the value of the sentence which is in a varible I het \U0001f61b. But I can't do api.GetSearch(print"\U0001f61b")...

Comment: I believe that `api.GetSearch(term=" ".encode('utf-8') ,lang="fr",count=200)` should work

Comment: I got this UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
 And with decode('utf-8') an empty list...